# UI caching with ItemsControl

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, itemscontrol

I have a performance problem in my WPF application. (I guess that's not a new thing...) Basically the application contains of a `ListBox` with items that can be selected, and a `ContentControl` that shows details for the selected item. For one type of item, there's an `ItemsControl` involved that displays a list of subitems. And this is the problem. As soon as I remove that `ItemsControl`, or only have it display a very small number of subitems (< 3), it's fast. But with 50 subitems, browsing through the list feels way too slow.

You'd probably suggest me some sort of virtualisation, but that doesn't apply here. In many cases, all items will fit on the screen, so they need to be displayed immediately anyway. No need to virtualise items that are out of sight.

I could strip down my whole application to just a few short classes (views and view models) that demonstrate the performance issue. This test case can be [downloaded here](http://unclassified.de/tmp/FieldLog-perftest.zip). Just run the application, select an item from the list on the left side and move to other items by pressing and holding the up or down arrow keys. Normally, this shows the other item instantly, but here it takes a very noticeable time of ~160 ms each.

The core of the view looks like this:

```
<UserControl ...>
  <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding StackFrameVMs, Mode=OneTime}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="•" Foreground="{Binding ...}"/>
            <TextBox Margin="4,0,0,0" Text="{Binding ...}"/>
            <TextBox Margin="12,0,0,0" Text="{Binding ...}"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
  </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

That's not a lot of UI controls, but I need them all. Actually there's a few more controls and bindings in my real application, but these are sufficient for the demo. When I move the contents of the `DataTemplate` to a separate `UserControl` and insert that instead, it takes even longer.

From previous profilings I believe that `ItemsControl` throws away and recreates all controls for the list items every time the list changes, because a different item is selected (and `DataContext` of the details view changes). Even if the view itself is reused because the new selected item has the same type and uses the same `DataTemplate`.

Is there a way to make `ItemsControl` reuse the items it has once created? Maybe even all of them, if one of the selected items needs fewer but the next needs more again? Or is there any way to improve the performance for this very simple use case in another way?

**Update:** BTW, note that this example code is a very much stripped down version of what my full application looks like. You might think you could simplify the structure I chose, but consider that the full application looks something like the following screenshot. There's more than just the `ItemsControl`, and there are different detail views for different item types selectable from the left list. So I basically need the structure I have, it just needs to be faster.

[image: Screenshot]

The whole project is open source, you may take a look at the complete solution if you like: https://github.com/dg9ngf/FieldLog

Comment: Just tested your application and I don't see any performance problem. It is totally responsive.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/E3iYjZC4

Comment: Can't reproduce. I tried with the code you provided (although I wouldn't be able to use it completely, because the ScrollViewer needs to stay there as it also contains more things). Your change is also slow here.

Comment: I've retested my demo with .NET 4.5(.1) on different computers with Win7x64 and Win8.1x64, it's slow everywhere. And it's definitely not my CPU... Going through the entire list takes 8 secs with fastest keyboard settings. It should take 2 secs.

Comment: Try a VirtualizingStackPanel and VirtualizationMode="Recycling"

Comment: Blam, that's what HighCore already suggested. It has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution but at the cost of start-up time.

Put the right hand list in an `ItemsControl` with a `Grid` as its panel, this will load every item at the start up but with a little change you can make it look just like before:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListBox Name="LogItemsList" ItemsSource="{Binding LogItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"/>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LogItems}" Grid.Column="1">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:FieldLogExceptionItemViewModel}">
                <v:FieldLogExceptionItemView Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVis}}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

</Grid>
```

Now add this to `MainViewModel`:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a bindable value that indicates SelectedItem
    /// </summary>
    public FieldLogExceptionItemViewModel SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (FieldLogExceptionItemViewModel)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(FieldLogExceptionItemViewModel), typeof(MainViewModel),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) =>
        {
            var vm = (MainViewModel)d;
            var val = (FieldLogExceptionItemViewModel)e.NewValue;
            if(val!=null)
            {
                foreach (FieldLogExceptionItemViewModel item in vm.LogItems)
                {
                    item.IsVisible = (item==val);
                }
            }
        }));
```

And add this to `FieldLogExceptionItemViewModel`:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a bindable value that indicates IsVisible
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsVisible
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsVisibleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsVisibleProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsVisibleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsVisible", typeof(bool), typeof(FieldLogExceptionItemViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

Then in order to speed it up even more:

Notice the `BooleanToVis` Converter. you need to implement a new `BooleanToVisibilityConvereter` because the system default converter uses `Visibility.Collapsed` when passed false and it causes the UI to reload the collapsed item after it's changed back to `Visibility.Visibile`, but what we need is a `Visibility.Hidden` since we need to keep everything ready at any time.

```
public class BooleanToVis : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

<Window.Resources>
    <v:BooleanToVis x:Key="BooleanToVis"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Hm, yeah, but that's going to be hard with thousands of list items (on the left side) which use virtualisation as well. (They just don't in my example because that list doesn't matter.) Actually, from what I see with other details views, the controls don't need to be present independently all the time, data binding is quick enough to just change the data in the existing controls. It's that single ItemsControl that's recreating items all the time. And that is super-slow in WPF. Also please not that this is just a very simple demo, see me update above.

Comment: At this point I suggest either put extra info in expander or change observableCollection to normal collection. when you add/remove items from observable collection it notifies with each change, use a simple list and notify the view only after the list is up to date.

Comment: the same goes for the rest of the VM. if you want it to work faster there are some tricks: use styles more, use canvas, notify all changes at once, avoid converters and code behind... you can search for more tips.